# mutt threads--display replies in inbox

Tags: email, gmail, mutt

While mutt has `set sort = threads` to show threaded "conversation" style messages, it doesn't display one's own replies in the threads. Instead, you have to change to the Sent folder to see your own messages. Is there any way to display one's own replies where they belong inside threads?

Comment: I've asked this question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131529/mutt-threads-display-replies-in-inbox

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I just found a solution that works for me, even though it is not pretty.

`set record = "+INBOX"`

I just set record to my inbox in my .muttrc, in that way the messages get threaded. It might not be ideal when I am the first sending an e-mail, but normally I will get an answer, so no issue.

Answer (score -1):

On my side, I like having a sent mails in a dedicated folder. So I set:

```
set record = "+Sent"
```

But I also set a *Bcc:* header to my own mailbox so that I can control if I want the mail in my inbox.

```
unmy_hdr Bcc:
my_hdr Bcc: $realname <$from>
```